# Access model from /protected/config/main.php

Tags: php, yii

I want to change a top menu in /protected/views/layouts/main.php so that it is stored in the database. I think to make it so: in /protected/config/main.php add in the array that returns from there an array of menu items:

```
return array(
    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'name' => 'My Web Application',
    'preload' => array('log'),
    'menu' => array(
        array('label' => 'Home', 'url' => array('/site/index')),
        array('label' => 'About', 'url' => array('/site/page')),
        array('label' => 'Contact', 'url' => array('/site/contact'))
    ),
```

But menu items should be taken from database like objects of Menu model class. The question that interests me is how I can access model from /protected/config/main.php.  If I write in /protected/config/main.php something like

```
$types = PageType::model()->findAll();
```

where PageType is existing model class, I get an error:

> Warning:
>   include(PageType.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   Z:\home\localhost\www\yii-1.1.16.bca042\framework\YiiBase.php on line
>   432
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'PageType.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.;/usr/local/php5/PEAR') in
>   Z:\home\localhost\www\yii-1.1.16.bca042\framework\YiiBase.php on line
>   432
>
> Fatal error: Class 'PageType' not found in
>   Z:\home\localhost\www\mycms\protected\config\main.php on line 8

I don't want to connect to the database directly from this script.

Comment: Why do you want to get your Menu data on protected/config/main? In protected/config/main all framework components are not initialized yet. I suggest you change your approach creating a component, for example protected/components/MainMenu, and using it on your protected/views/layouts/main. In this component you can perform any operation, for example get data, build your menu and render it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Component is realy what I need.

Comment: All done. It's realy cool, now I can to add menu items from automatic generated form.

Comment: Nice! Please auto answer the question and close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All done. I do it with using component instead of /config/main.php

Comment: Can you please post details of your solution to make this answer more meaningful and helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

I am just created in /protected/components/ directory a component class

```
class MainMenu extends CComponent {

private $items;

public function getItems() {
    $types=MainMenuItem::model()->findAll();
    return $types;
}
```

and used this component in /protected/views/layouts/main.php

```
$mainMenu = new MainMenu();
$itemsModel = $mainMenu->items;
$items = array();
foreach ($itemsModel as $m) {
    $label = $m->label;
    $url = $m->url;
    if (!empty($m->visible) && $m->visible == 'isGuest' && !Yii::app()->user->isGuest 
        || !empty($m->visible) && $m->visible != 'isGuest' && Yii::app()->user->isGuest) 
        continue;
    $item = array('label'=>$label . ($label == 'Logout' ? '('.Yii::app()->user->name.')' : ''), 'url'=>array($url));
    $items[] = $item;
}
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array('items'=>$items));
```